# Automation tool suggestions for specific software (I think C#)

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation, automated-tests, autoit

I want to automate a `GUI` of `windows software` (Not build-in in windows).

In general for these tasks i use `autoit software` and it works great.

Now with this specific software there is an incompatibility with `autoit` and i can't find the elements in the software with `autoit` info.

I think the software was written with `C#` (it requires `.NET` framework to be installed).

Is there any idea on how can I control this software ? Any alternative `automation tool` that can do the work ?

Thanks.

Edit: The problematic software name is SearchDiggity.

And I'm not sure the software written in C#, It's just an assumption  because of the .NET requirement.

Comment: I've never encountered something built in C# (Winforms/WPF/Silverlight) that I couldn't get the elements for in AutoIT.  Is it possible this is some sort of flash window running on top of a C# program?  Is the software something that is commercially available that you can name?

Comment: Yes, The software name is SearchDiggity.

You can download it from here : [link](http://www.stachliu.com/resources/tools/google-hacking-diggity-project/attack-tools/)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I installed AutoIt v3 (x86 version on an x64 box) and SearchDiggity v3.03.  I was able to run SearchDiggity and then use use the AutoIT Window Info tool to look at the SearchDiggity window.  I couldn't get the information for the individual elements either.  You might be able to select the window and then tag/use the arrow keys to select the correct control and navigate that way, though it's not nearly as clean as just selecting the control.

Comment: SearchDiggity is using .Net 4.0 and WPF.  The window appears to be an HwndWrapper according to AutoIt.  I'm not sure why the individual controls can't be "seen" by the Window Info tool.

Comment: I know there is option to control it through the arrows and tabs.
But there is no such software that can handle the internal elements of the SearchDiggity?
Or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another tool might work:
[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)
or here is a list of GUI testing tools on Wikipedia:
[GUI Testing Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools)

Though I agree with @Narthring. I have never found a C# program that I cannot automate and get elements with in AutoIT.

Comment: I added the software name.
I saw this list in wikipedia but tried some of them with no success.
I will be very happy if you can help me with it.
I edited my message with my problematic software name

Comment: The Sikuli tool works good.
It's a very good tool.
I didn't know it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) might be useful for such tasks as well. It allows image-based automation (exactly like Sikuli), as well as text-based. For example, you can do things like:

```
click("File", "Save")
write("DocumentName", into="File name:")
press(ENTER)
```

etc. This is usually much quicker than automation using screenshots.

It works well with .NET/WPF applications (small example is available at http://www.getautoma.com/examples/automate-wpf-tree-navigation).

*Disclosure: I'm one of [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) developers.*